# Postgres INNER JOIN ERROR: schema "bar" does not exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, column-alias

I am trying to do an inner join between two tables, foo and bar.  the relation is one-to-many.  a bar needs a foo, and a foo can have any number of bars.  Confusingly, both tables have columns named "name" and "id".  When I run my query, I'd like to rename those fields on the bar table to "bar_id" and "bar_name" respectively.  This is the query that I have:

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.id 'bar_id', bar.name 'bar_name' FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id=bar.foo_id;
```

When I run this query, I get: `ERROR:  schema "bar" does not exist` on bar.id

I tried using aliases for the two table names, f and b, and I got the same error.

I tried removing "bar", eg:

```
SELECT foo.*, id 'bar_id', name 'bar_name' FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id=bar.foo_id;
```

and I get:  `ERROR:  type "id" does not exist`

If I remove "id", it works, but instead of aliasing the column name, it replaces the actual VALUE in that column in each row:

```
SELECT foo.*, name 'bar_name' FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id=bar.foo_id;
```

yields:

```
id |  name |   name     
1  |  abc  | bar_name
```

("bar_name" should actually be "def")

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here?  How can I fix this?

Comment: `id 'bar_id'` should be `id "bar_id"` or simply `id bar_id` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard SQL, which Postgres follows in that regard, single quotes stand for literal strings. Use double quotes instead of single quotes for the identifiers (the aliases in your `select` clause) - or better yet, not quotes at all:

```
SELECT 
    f.*, 
    b.id as bar_id, 
    b.name as bar_name 
FROM foo f
INNER JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.foo_id;
```